# how to generate Alternate +1 & -1 sequence in MATLAB simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, encoder

this is my first time using the MATLAB simulink i am trying to make a (Non-Return-to-Zero) level encoder , i cant fined a component for that, can any one help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the time for the signal to spend at 1 and -1 is constant you could use a [`Pulse Block`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/pulsegenerator.html) with amplitude 2 and shift it down by 1.  This generates a square wave.

Otherwise, you could use a [`Repeating Sequence Stair`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/repeatingsequencestair.html) block to do this.  This block takes a vector of values `[1, 2, 7, -1, 3]` and repeats a square signal by outputting and holding each of those values for the sample time.

Answer (score 0):

This will generate NRZ pulse of specified width.

```
clc
Fs = 200;           % sampling frequency in Hz (you can change it)
Ts = 1/Fs;          % sampling interval
Tot_time = 100;             % total time in seconds (you can change it)
width = 20;                 % width of NRZ pulse in seconds (you can change it)
time = 0:Ts:Tot_time-Ts;    % time on x-axis
modulous = mod(time, width);   
signal = (2*(modulous<width/2))-1; 
plot(time,signal);                 % plots the signal versus time
axis([0 Tot_time -1.5 1.5]);       % adjusts the range of x-axis and y-axis
```